# Count for each month-Year, how many times a number (1/2/3) appear in a column range

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2016

Experts,

I need  help in counting error types(1|2|3) for each month of a year.
As you can see in the image below, cells may have multiple error types for a single entry separated by comma.

I couldn't figure out how to count exact number of entries for each error types for each month of year.

below formula is just calculating for single entries.

```
=COUNTIFS($J$7:$J$19,"<="&EOMONTH($M8,0),$J$7:$J$19,">"&EOMONTH($M8,-1),$K$7:$K$19,O$7)
```

and below formula counts how many entries of 1's, 2's and 3 are in column, 
but I couldn't figure it out how to combine with above formula to get the required Output?

```
=(LEN(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,K7:K19))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,K7:K19),S7,"")))/LEN(S7)
```

any help ??

see the image 
[image]

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: I posted an answer based on the dataset you gave. An alternative option is to reformat your data, then a pivot table could also solve your problem.

Comment: @gns100 Thanks for taking time to explain it well, and pivot table is not suitable in my circumstances else it was the easiest approach to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can embed your second formula as a countifs criteria. Even if you could, it would give you the wrong result as the result is a count of a criteria (e.g., 5 twos) instead of being the criteria (2). But maybe you already now this. The reason your formula as is doesn't work is that excel considers numbers (cell K13 is a number) differently from text (cell K14 is text).

Knowing this, I would solve as follows: use your existing formula (to count values) and then copy and add this copy to your original. Then change the criteria of the copied section to `"*"&O$7&"*"` (to count the text occurences). FYI, the * are wildcards, so it is looking for the text in any location.

The formula would look like this

`=COUNTIFS($J$7:$J$19,"<="&EOMONTH($M8,0),$J$7:$J$19,">"&EOMONTH($M8,-1),$K$7:$K$19,O$7)+COUNTIFS($J$7:$J$19,"<="&EOMONTH($M8,0),$J$7:$J$19,">"&EOMONTH($M8,-1),$K$7:$K$19,"*"&O$7&"*")`

There are alternatives such as using an array as your second criteria (no need for adding the second countifs, but need to wrap with `=SUM()`  or using the `=SUMPRODUCT()` formula.